# Label on HeaderIcon in HeaderControls

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I want to put a label next to an icon so user can better understand what is this clickable icon for.
This icon appear in the HeaderControl of a com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Window

```java
String promptNewThing = "Add some thing";
String imgNewThingText = "../servlet/servletOperation?cmd=Icon&time=" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "&text=" + promptNewThing;
HeaderIcon iconNewThing = new HeaderIcon("buttons/new.png");
HeaderIcon iconNewThingLabel = new HeaderIcon(imgNewThingText);
newThing = new HeaderControl(iconNewThing, clickHandlerNewThing);
newThing.setPrompt(promptNewThing);
newThingLabel = new HeaderControl(iconNewThingLabel, clickHandlerNewThing);
newThingLabel.setPrompt(promptNewThing);

setHeaderControls(HeaderControls.HEADER_LABEL, NewThing, NewThingLabel, HeaderControls.MINIMIZE_BUTTON, HeaderControls.MAXIMIZE_BUTTON, HeaderControls.CLOSE_BUTTON);
```

For information : In this code, Servlet URL return an image made from the text `promptNewThing`
But iconNewThingLabel is an Icon which has the width of an Icon, too small.

The result of this code :
[image: Result with icon from text is to small]
The small white square we can see between first Icon is `newThingLabel`.

**Is there a way to add a label at the right of an HeaderIcon ?**

For example I would to have something like :

[image: Icon and Label]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Manu I have done the same thing as you have done. The only change is instead of adding `HeaderIcon` (`iconNewThingLabel` in your case - if it's representing the text), I have used a `com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Label` & added that as a `headerControl`. Code snippet is as follows:

```
Label label = new Label("test header");
setHeaderControls(HeaderControls.HEADER_LABEL, NewThing, label, HeaderControls.MINIMIZE_BUTTON, HeaderControls.MAXIMIZE_BUTTON, HeaderControls.CLOSE_BUTTON);
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Sometime solution is so simple... Thanks ! I have add the clickHandler on the Label too and it works !